# Need help on entity framework core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am having issues getting the exact data when using below EF Core query in asp.net core mvc, when there are no records in customer table for a particular account, then i am getting 1 instead of 0 when i use count() with left join in the below EF query.

Can someone help in fixing this.

```
var AccountData = from acclist in _dbcontext.Accout
                               join departmentlist in _dbcontext.Departments on acclist.DepartmentId equals departmentlist.DepartmentId
                               join statuslist in _dbcontext.Statuses on acclist.StatusId equals statuslist.StatusId
                               join customerlist in _dbcontext.Customers on acclist.CustomerId equals customerlist.CustomerId into leftjoin
                               from custlist in leftjoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
                               where acclist.CaseStatusId == 2
                               group custlist by new { acclist.CaseID, acclist.AccName, acclist.AccNumber, acclist.CaseName, departmentlist.DepartmentName, statuslist.StatusName } into g
                               select new
                               {
                                   _accId = g.Key.AccountID,
                                   _accName = g.Key.AccountName,
                                   _accNumber = g.Key.AccNumber,
                                   _status = g.Key.StatusName,
                                   _department = g.Key.DepartmentName,
                                   _caseName = g.Key.CaseName,
                                   _dataSize = g.Sum(customerlist => customerlist.DataSize),
                                   _customerCount = g.Count()
                               };
```

The Actual T-SQL Query is

```
select Account.CaseID, Account.AccNumber,Account.AccountName,
Account.CaseName, Departments.DepartmentName,Statuses.StatusName,
Sum(Customer.DataSize), Count(CustomerID)
from Account
inner join Departments on Account.DepartmentId = Departments.DepartmentId
inner join Statuses on Account.StatusId = statuses.StatusId
left join Customer on Account.CustomerId = Customer.CustomerId
where Account.StatusId = 2
group by Account.CaseID,Account.AccNumber,Account.AccountName,Account.CaseName,
Departments.DepartmentName,Statuses.StatusName
```

Comment: Then why are you left (outer) joining Customer? Why are do you use `join` at all, in stead of navigation properties?

Comment: can you tell me an example about navigation properties. I am pretty new to ef core and this is my first project. Basically each account has one or more customers. I want to do a left join incase if an account is created but the customers are not created yet and later a user can edit the account and add multiple customer. In my data table i want to populate the account and no of customers and size of their data

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key

Comment: From a design perspective, also consider SQL Server views and a DBSET in C# to access them. Using SQL Views and Stored Procedures is more efficient than LINQ and is easier to code for more difficult cases - as long as your SQL experience is able to get the best from this approach.. You can, as already suggested, use LINQ navigation techniques within a single LINQ query to bring back a hierarchical set of data based on your starting point in the data.